# Google App Script : Pasting Values only in new spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dashboard on a gsheet spreadsheet, with one sheet being an overview. It has tables generated by various QUERY Functions. I want to create a script that would make a copy of this sheet only, and save it into a new Spreadsheet, stored on a Google Drive folder.

I managed to do this, but then the result does not display my queries, it just copies the formula.
Here is my code :

```
function CopyToSpreadSheet() {

  //Source sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MTS");
  //Name new sheet in target SpreadSheet
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Archive " + formattedDate;
  //Create new spreadsheet
  var newss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  var newss_id = newss.getId();
  var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(newss_id);
  newfile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById('1EUFJcySQ_Mv8qD8OzYUX1QniXQy2gjw0'));

  //open target SpreadSheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newss_id);

  //CopyTo...
  var targetSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(target);
  targetSheet.setName(name);
    
  return;
}
```

So, i've been trying the CopyTo parameters `{contentsOnly:true}` and `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES`, which gives me *The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet,(class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo* for the ContentsOnly parameter, and *The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo* for the CopypasteType.

At this point, I have no idea how to fix this, but it is clearly coming from me not knowing how to handle this. I've also tried to use `.makeCopy`, but there was no parameter to force the copy to use the Values and not the formula in itself.

Any ideas? I'm open to anything at this point!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please share a copy/sample of your spreadsheet so we can picture how your spreadsheet currently is. Remove sensitive data if any. Also share what is the current output and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your title of `Google App Script : Pasting Values only in new spreadsheet` and `I want to create a script that would make a copy of this sheet only, and save it into a new Spreadsheet, stored on a Google Drive folder.`, you want to copy only the values from the source sheet to the target sheet in a new Spreadsheet by using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- First, about the reason for your issue of `So, i've been trying the CopyTo parameters {contentsOnly:true} and SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, which gives me The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet,(class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo for the ContentsOnly parameter, and The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo for the CopypasteType.`, I thought that you might have used the method of `copyTo(destination, options)` of Class Range to Class Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, such an error occurs and the reason for this is due to it.

In order to copy only the values from a source sheet to a destination sheet, I thought that there might be the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `getValues` and `setValues` are used.

```js
function CopyToSpreadSheet() {
  // Source sheet side.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MTS");
  var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

  // This is from your script.
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = ss.getName() + " Archive " + formattedDate;
  var newss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  var newss_id = newss.getId();
  var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(newss_id);
  newfile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById('1EUFJcySQ_Mv8qD8OzYUX1QniXQy2gjw0'));

  // Destination sheet side.
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newss_id);
  var targetSheet = target.getSheets()[0];
  targetSheet.setName(sourceSheet.getSheetName()); // If you don't want to rename sheet name, please remove this line.
  targetSheet.getRange(range.getA1Notation()).setNumberFormats(range.getNumberFormats()).setValues(range.getValues());
}
```

- When this script is run, only the values are copied from the source sheet to the destination sheet. In this sample, the number format is also copied.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `copyTo` methods of Class Sheet and Class Spreadsheet are used.

```js
function CopyToSpreadSheet() {
  // Source sheet side.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MTS");
  var tempSheet1 = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss);
  var tempRange1 = tempSheet1.getDataRange();
  tempRange1.copyTo(tempRange1, { contentsOnly: true });

  // This is from your script.
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = ss.getName() + " Archive " + formattedDate;
  var newss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  var newss_id = newss.getId();
  var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(newss_id);
  newfile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById('1EUFJcySQ_Mv8qD8OzYUX1QniXQy2gjw0'));

  // Destination sheet side.
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newss_id);
  var tempSheet2 = tempSheet1.copyTo(target);
  var targetSheet = target.getSheets()[0];
  targetSheet.setName(sourceSheet.getSheetName()); // If you don't want to rename sheet name, please remove this line.
  const tempRange2 = tempSheet2.getDataRange();
  tempRange2.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("A1"));

  // Remove temp sheets.
  ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet1);
  target.deleteSheet(tempSheet2);
}
```

- When this script is run, not only the values but also background colors, font styles, and so on are copied from the source sheet to the destination sheet.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: You indeed understood well what I wanted, sorry if my title or explanations were misleading. I've tried both solutions, and the second one was working, while the first one managed to copy text but not the numbers. Would you have any idea why ? Other than this, Thanks a lot for taking the time to help, I appreciate it ! And the more I explore this, the more I understand that I'm seriously lacking the basics of all this..

Comment: @Nelerdeth Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I've tried both solutions, and the second one was working, while the first one managed to copy text but not the numbers. Would you have any idea why ?`, when I tested my 1st script, I cannot replicate your situation. Unfortunately, the number can be copied. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Poor skills ? You're a savior man :D thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Since no example given I'm assuming you are using the `Query` function without `importrange` which only works within the same spreadsheet.

**Try:**

```
=query(importrange("URL", "Dashboard!A1:A"), "select Col1", 0)
```

Replace the `URL` with your **Source Spreadsheet URL** and the Range to refer to.

### Source Spreadsheet:

[image]

[image]

**Result:**
[image]
This is the result I got using your code, only the drive folder ID was changed. I am able to get the actual data/values not only the formula.

**Explanation:**

The reason is using the normal Query function it can only get data from the same Spreadsheet file. Same with normally pasting your Query formula in a different spreadsheet, it will not be able to get the data. For it to be able to Query data from other Spreadsheet you need to use it with importrange.

Also don't forget to change access to the file so those who use it for Query will actually be able to retrieve the data.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Query From Another Spreadsheet](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-query-another-sheet/)